Using UIAppFonts From Main App With Fonts Bundled In A Swift Package
Context
I have a swift package with design styles and components reused across projects. One of these styles is fonts. There is a Fonts.xcassets (composed of nested .ttf files) that is processed as a resource.
Question
Using these fonts is easy enough if we register them with CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont (e.g. from the AppDelegate).
But, from an iOS app, it is preferable to register custom font styles using UIAppFonts in the Info.plist as documented in these Apple docs. This would work with SwiftUI previews too.
Since the package's Fonts.xcassets doesn't seem to be copied as a resource to the main app bundle, UIAppFonts doesn't work AFAIK. Is there a way to use fonts defined in a package with UIAppFonts?
Copy Resource Script (Not Ideal)
We could copy the package's .xcassets into the bundle resources with a script:
FONT_DIR="${SRCROOT}/Path/To/SwiftPackage/Resources/Fonts.xcassets"
DEST_DIR="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app"
cp "$FONT_DIR"/*.ttf "$DEST_DIR"

But the path to the swift package would be the derived data, which is very messy.
